# Not able to write to excel using openpyxl in python

Tags: python, selenium, openpyxl

Can someone please provide the below java code in Python

```
public static void testActualResultsStoring(String sheetname, int rownumber, String ActualResults) 
{

   try {

      InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(a);


      Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

      Sheet sheet = wb.getSheet(sheetname);

      Row row = sheet.getRow(rownumber);

      int num = row.getLastCellNum();

      Cell cell = row.createCell(num++);

      cell.setCellValue(ActualResults);

      FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(a);

      wb.write(fileOut);

      fileOut.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

   }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried anything by yourself?

Comment: Yes but not able to get the correct solution. can you please help on this?

Comment: you can try using `xlsxwriter` , read the docs here https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/getting_started.html

Comment: Add the non-correct solution to the question, and also info about what is wrong with it

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a work request which are off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Lot of adjustments, naturally, porting from one language to another. Included notes in the code, to try and help explain. However, code should run, assuming you have some file called "test.xlsx" with a sheet called "Sheet1".

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
#Import libraries

def testActualResultsStoring(sheetname, rownumber, ActualResults):
    try:
        #Define file directory
        fileDir = 'test.xlsx'

        #wb file needs to load off of string that has file directory
        wb = load_workbook(fileDir)
        #Find sheet based on provided sheet name
        sheet = wb[sheetname]
        #No ++ in python, so we'll just find num and add 1 to it here. Note, max_column considers the entire sheet, so a more complicated answer is in order if the sheet has columns that aren't 100% filled.
        num = sheet.max_column + 1
        #No need to define a cell variable, can just assign value while calling it.
        sheet.cell(row=rownumber, column=num, value=ActualResults)

        #Save and close file
        wb.save(fileDir)
        wb.close()

    #Except case
    except(exception):
        exception.printStackTrace()

#Call on method 
testActualResultsStoring('Sheet1', 1, '1')
```